# How do I use constants in haskell, to avoid magic numbers?

Tags: haskell, constants

Say I have a list of numbers from 1 to MAGIC_NUMBER -- Is there a way I can declare this beforehand ?

Comment: What you mean by "declaring numbers"?

Comment: A very important point you should clarify: when do you know the magic number? If you know it at compile time then Chuck has the right answer below.

Answer (score 58):

Sure. In fact, given that Haskell is purely functional, it's much easier to define a constant than a non-constant.

```
magicNumber = 42

magicList = [1..magicNumber]
```

Answer (score 41):

Chuck's and ony's  answers are correct. There's one trap you should be aware of:

```
magicNum = 42

f magicNum = 'A'
f _ = 'B'
```

is NOT what you might expect - `magicNum` in second line is a pattern that matches everything, just like `f x = 'A'`. Use `f x | x == magicNum = 'A'`.

Comment: In fact, you can even rebind standard operators this way. For example, if you define the function `f (==) a b = a == b`, and then call `f div 8 4`, the result will be 2, not false. (This is, of course, kind of a pathological thing to do.)

Comment: So what if I *want* to do what one would expect from that code? I.e. the line "f magicNum" should define "f 42" and nothing selse?

Answer (score 15):

You can use algebraic data in all your calculations and use some named values if they are really "magic", or build render of algebraic values to "magic" numbers and many more:

```
class FlagsMask f where mask :: f -> Int

data Magics = Alpha | Beta | Gamma
    deriving (Enum, Read, Show, Eq, Ord)

instance FlagsMask Magics where
    mask m = 2 ^ fromEnum m

data PermsFlag = FlagRead | FlagWrite | FlagExec | FlagSuper

-- [flagRead, flagWrite, flagExec] = [2^n | n <- [0..2]]
(flagRead : flagWrite : flagExec : _) = [2^n | n <- [0..]]
flagSuper = 16

instance FlagsMask PermsFlag  where
    mask FlagRead = flagRead
    mask FlagWrite = flagWrite
    mask FlagExec = flagExec
    mask FlagSuper = flagSuper
```

```
*Main> map fromEnum [Alpha .. ]
[0,1,2]
it :: [Int]
*Main> zip [Alpha .. ] [1..]
[(Alpha,1),(Beta,2),(Gamma,3)]
it :: [(Magics, Integer)]
```